# Insert nonexistent columns in matrix or dataframe in given order

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am on the lookout for a function in R that would check for the presence of particular columns, e.g.

```
cols=c("a","b","c","d")
```

in a matrix or dataframe that would insert a column with `NA`s in case any columns did not exist (in the position in which the columns are given in vector `cols`). Say if you had a matrix or dataframe with named columns `"a", "d"`, that it would insert a column `"b"` and `"c"` filled up with `NA`s before column `"d"`, and that any columns not listed in `cols` would be deleted (e.g. column `"e"`). What would be the easiest and fastest way to achieve this (I am dealing with a fairly large dataset of ca. 1 million rows)? Or is there already some function that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the creation step and the ordering step. Here is an example:

```
cols <- letters[1:4]
## initialize test data set
my.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), d = rnorm(100), e = rnorm(100))
## exclude columns not in cols
my.df <- my.df[ , colnames(my.df) %in% cols]
## add missing columns filled with NA
my.df[, cols[!(cols %in% colnames(my.df))]] <- NA
## reorder
my.df <- my.df[, cols]
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! Other approach I found in the meanwhile was to use match, e.g. coln=c("a","b","c","d")
colnmatrix=colnames(matrix)
matrix=matrix[,match(coln,colnmatrix)]
colnames(matrix)=coln

Comment: @TomWenseleers you shoul post it as an answer so that people could upvote (might be the better approach)

Comment: Your method will only work for data.frames, his will only work for matrices. Data.frames being more general (you can always turn a matrix to a data.frame then back to a matrix without losing info), I prefer yours for now.

Answer (score 2):

Other approach I also just discovered using match, but only works for matrices:

```
# original matrix
matrix=cbind(a = 1:2, d = 3:4)
# required columns
coln=c("a","b","c","d")

colnmatrix=colnames(matrix)
matrix=matrix[,match(coln,colnmatrix)]
colnames(matrix)=coln
matrix
     a  b  c d
[1,] 1 NA NA 3
[2,] 2 NA NA 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility if your data is in a matrix

```
# original matrix
m1 <- cbind(a = 1:2, d = 3:4)
m1
#      a d
# [1,] 1 3
# [2,] 2 4

# matrix will all columns, filled with NA
all.cols <- letters[1:4]
m2 <- matrix(nrow = nrow(m1), ncol = length(all.cols), dimnames = list(NULL, all.cols))
m2
#       a  b  c  d
# [1,] NA NA NA NA
# [2,] NA NA NA NA

# replace columns in 'NA matrix' with values from original matrix
m2[ , colnames(m1)] <- m1
m2
#      a  b  c d
# [1,] 1 NA NA 3
# [2,] 2 NA NA 4
```